# Date based sql aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate, vertica

I have a set of columns F_no,F_date and F_weight. Now For each F_date and F_no I have sum(F_weight). That's pretty easy.

What I want to do now is , for each F_date and F_no I want to aggregate on  F_weight for (F_date-1) and (F_date-2). 
The table structure would look like :

**| F_no | F_date | sum(F_date) | (F_date-1) | sum(F_date-1) | (F_date-2) | sum(F_date-2) |**

Can anyone please help me out with this issue ? 
Thank You

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you mean? 
(I agree, you could have formulated your question more clearly , but sometimes it seems to be our task, too, to make sense of cryptic questions ...)

```
WITH
input(f_no,f_date,f_weight) AS (
          SELECT 42,'2017-01-01',30
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-01',30
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-02',25
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-02',25
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-03',20
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-03',20
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-04',15
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-04',15
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-05',10
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-05',10
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-06', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 42,'2017-01-06', 5
)
,
as_vertical AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    f_no
  , f_date
  , SUM(f_weight) OVER(PARTITION BY f_no,f_date) AS weight_sum
  FROM input
)
-- now as pivot ...
SELECT
  f_no
, f_date
    , weight_sum
, LAG(f_date    ,1) OVER(PARTITION BY f_no ORDER BY f_date) AS f_date_1
, LAG(weight_sum,1) OVER(PARTITION BY f_no ORDER BY f_date) AS weight_sum_1
, LAG(f_date    ,2) OVER(PARTITION BY f_no ORDER BY f_date) AS f_date_2
, LAG(weight_sum,2) OVER(PARTITION BY f_no ORDER BY f_date) AS weight_sum_2
FROM as_vertical;

f_no|f_date    |weight_sum|f_date_1  |weight_sum_1|f_date_2  |weight_sum_2
  42|2017-01-01|        60|(null)    |(null)      |(null)    |(null)
  42|2017-01-02|        50|2017-01-01|          60|(null)    |(null)
  42|2017-01-03|        40|2017-01-02|          50|2017-01-01|          60
  42|2017-01-04|        30|2017-01-03|          40|2017-01-02|          50
  42|2017-01-05|        20|2017-01-04|          30|2017-01-03|          40
  42|2017-01-06|        10|2017-01-05|          20|2017-01-04|          30
```

I should add: You can do this in Vertica, because it supports OLAP functions (`LAG()` and `SUM() OVER()` ) . MySql does not, I'm afraid ...